# VoiceXML without Telephone

Tags: vxml

I want to run my Vxml application locally without using Telephone.

IS it possible or not? If so please tell me software which is needed and also direct me how  to run?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Voxeo's Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/products/voicexml-ivr-platform.jsp).  You can download a 2 port version of their software for free and it runs VoiceXML and CCXML.  It is highly compliant with the standards since they have employees on the standards committee.  It comes with a free Text-To-Speech (TTS) and speech recognition system.  Their extreme tech support is also free. It also comes with SIP softphone that you can use to place calls into it using your PC's mic and speakers.  You can go to [this blog](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2011/11/testing-your-voicexml-app-with-voxeo.html) for more information on how to install and test VoiceXML applications on Prophecy.